# ClearInterval js stop current execution

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, dom-events

I have a Vue 2.0 app in which I use this line in order to call `this.refreshState()` every min.

```
this.scheduler = setInterval(() => this.refreshState(), 60 * 1000)
```

Later in the code I need to make sure that the *execution loop* is stopped and also that if there's an instance of `this.refreshState()` currently running (from the `setInterval` scheduler) it's stopped as well (even if it's in the middle of doing stuff).

So far I'm using :

```
clearInterval(this.scheduler)
```

as per (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)

The question I'm having is does `clearInterval` blocks the current execution if any? I can't find the answer in the doc unfortunately.

FYI the code of refreshState:

```
refreshState: function () {
   // API call to backend
    axios.get("/api/refreshState")
       .then(response => {
            this.states = response.data.states
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err)
}
```

Here's my use case :

```
alterState: function (incremental_state) {
    clearInterval(this.scheduler) // ???
    axios.post("/api/alterState", incremental_state)
      .then(() => {
           this.refreshState()
           this.scheduler = setInterval(() => this.refreshState(), 60 * 1000)
        })
      .catch((err) => { console.log(error) })
}
```

I want to make sure that when i exit `alterState` , the variable `this.states` takes into account the addition of incremental state.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded, so technically there can't be a "current execution" at the moment you are calling `clearInterval`. I suppose you mean that `this.refreshState()` does some `async` stuff; in that case, no, those promises won't be cancelled for you.

Comment: You can't stop a function from running, if it's running already

Comment: yes indeed refreshState is doind a axios.get() basically. Arf that's too bad. Do you think there's a workaround / a change in code design i could use ?

Comment: (added some context to clarify the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From...

> *I want to make sure that when i exit alterState, the variable `this.states` takes into account the addition of incremental state.*

...I understand you're performing a change on backend and you want it reflected on frontend. *And that currently that **doesn't happen**, although you're calling* `this.refreshState()` *right after getting a successful response from* `/api/alterState`. <sup>***1***</sup>

To achieve this functionality, it's not enough to call `this.refreshState()`, because your browser, by default, caches the result (it remembers the recent calls and their results, so it serves the previous result from cache, instead of calling the server again), unless the endpoint is specifically configured to disable caching.

To disable caching for a particular endpoint, you could either

- configure the endpoint (server side) to tell browsers: *"Hey, my stuff is time sensitive, don't cache it!"* (won't go into how, as I have no idea what technology you're using on backend and it varies). Roughly it means setting appropriate response headers.
- or call the endpoint with a unique param, each time. This makes the endpoint *"change"* from browser's POV, so it's always going to request  from server:

```js
  axios
    .get(`/api/refreshState?v=${Date.now()}`)
    .then...
```

I recommend the second option, it's reliable, predictable and does not depend on server configuration.

---

And, unless something else, other than the current app instance (some other user, or other server scripts, etc...) make changes to the data, you don't actually need a `setInterval`. I suggest removing it.

But If you *do* have other sources changing server-side data, (and you do want to refresh it regardless of user interactions with the app), what you have works perfectly fine, there's no need to even cancel the existing interval when you make a change + `refreshState()`). <sup>***2***</sup>

---

<sup>***1***</sup> - if I misunderstood your question and that is not your problem, please clarify your question, right now it's a bit unclear
<sup>***2***</sup> - as side-note and personal preference, I suggest renaming `refreshState()` to `getState()`

Comment: Hi Tao, Thx for the answer. So yes you got the question right. Well I need the getState() function (refreshState) because there's indeed some work happening on the server that can lead to alteration of the states database table.
getState() purpose is to get a list of tasks that can be processed by the user in the UI ( a reactive component). So my biggest fear is that the user processes the task in the UI then calls alterState (via UI component) but in the meantime a 'background' getState() triggers and provide to user the exact same list, allowing him to process again the exact same task.

Comment: So your *"states"* are actually jobs/tasks and you want to make sure one that has been altered is not being altered again. The typical solution is to use unique identifiers (`uuid`s). And then, once a job is processed, you mark it as processed and when it's loaded again in `getState()` it's marked as done. I can't help you without more context, I'm afraid.

Comment: If you're worried the same "task" can be processed twice and "processing" takes time. perhaps you should mark a task as "in progress" when the user starts processing it, basically locking it. Unlocking would be automatic, after a period of time, at the end of which you could ask the user if they want to lock it for another time interval.  Another possible route is to re-fetch the tasks before submitting a processed one. If you discover it has already been processed, prompt the user about the conflict and ask them to resolve it: cancel vs overwrite.

Comment: Indeed i think that's the best option. Having a mutable property that basically says if alterState is running then disregard the execution of getState